# TSQL - Creating a consolidated schedule from contiguous schedule parts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am having the absolute worst time trying to consolidate a list of schedule parts into a more concise list when start and end times match. The code below is for a single schedule, and the code is a reference to what is happening at that time for the user.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```
declare @t as table (code int, dtDate DateTime, dtStart DateTime, dtEnd DateTime)

insert into @t values
(46,'2017-01-23','2017-01-23 06:00','2017-01-23 14:45'),
(127,'2017-01-23','2017-01-23 07:30','2017-01-23 08:00'),
(127,'2017-01-23','2017-01-23 08:00','2017-01-23 08:15'),
(127,'2017-01-23','2017-01-23 08:15','2017-01-23 10:00'),
(76,'2017-01-23','2017-01-23 10:00','2017-01-23 10:45'),
(127,'2017-01-23','2017-01-23 10:45','2017-01-23 13:00'),
(127,'2017-01-23','2017-01-23 13:00','2017-01-23 13:15'),
(127,'2017-01-23','2017-01-23 13:15','2017-01-23 14:30')

select * from @t


-- Current Output
code        dtDate                  dtStart                 dtEnd
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
46          2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 06:00:00.000 2017-01-23 14:45:00.000
127         2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 07:30:00.000 2017-01-23 08:00:00.000
127         2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 08:00:00.000 2017-01-23 08:15:00.000
127         2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 08:15:00.000 2017-01-23 10:00:00.000
76          2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 10:00:00.000 2017-01-23 10:45:00.000
127         2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 10:45:00.000 2017-01-23 13:00:00.000
127         2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 13:00:00.000 2017-01-23 13:15:00.000
127         2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 13:15:00.000 2017-01-23 14:30:00.000

-- Expected Output
code        dtDate                  dtStart                 dtEnd
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
46          2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 06:00:00.000 2017-01-23 14:45:00.000
127         2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 07:30:00.000 2017-01-23 10:00:00.000
76          2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 10:00:00.000 2017-01-23 10:45:00.000
127         2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 10:45:00.000 2017-01-23 14:30:00.000
```

Comment: Explain your logic. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a classic Gaps & Islands

```
Select Code
      ,dtDate
      ,dtStart = min(dtStart)
      ,dtEnd   = max(dtEnd)
 From  (
        Select * 
              ,Grp = Row_Number() over (Partition By Code,dtDate Order By dtStart) - Row_Number() over (Order by dtEnd)
         From @t
       ) A
 Group By Code,dtDate,Grp
 Order By min(dtStart)
```

Returns

[image]